# Jersey Singleton instantiated multiple time

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, tomcat8

I have to make a very small REST app and even if i'm used to Spring, Jersey seems lighter than Spring (maybe I'm wrong?).

I use Jersey 2.25 on a Tomcat 8.0.39.

I have a DAO class that currently access a text file (will be upgrade to a jdbc connection). Those read/write operations must be synchronized, hence I want my DAO instance to be a singleton.

```
@Singleton
public class ModelDao extends IModelDao
    public ModelDao() {
        System.out.println("init ModelDao");
    }

    @Override
    public MyModel read(int id){...}
}
```

This singleton is injected in a service:

```
@Path("/Model/")
public class ModelService {

    @Inject
    private IModelDao modelDao;

    @Path("{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public MyModel getModel(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
        return modelDao.read(id);
    }
}
```

Through a binder

```
public class DaoBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ModelDao.class).to(IModelDao.class);
    }
}
```

In a `ResourceConfig`, I register the binder and my packages.
When I use my service, I get the correct data but the `ModelDao` constructor is called on each request. So the read/write operations are not synchronized.

I understood a class annotated `@Singleton` was supposed to be instantiated only once in my app.
Does I get it wrong?

Comment: singleton is the default scope in spring, so just leave your bean definitions as they are, without explicitly specifying the scope attribute.

Comment: Are you using guice di?

Comment: I'm neither using spring nor guice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding a service through the `AbstractBinder` with Jersey, the `@Singleton` annotation is not supported. You need to use the `bind().to().in(Scope)` syntax, where `Scope` would be e.g. `Singleton.class`, `RequestScoped.class`. The default scope is `PerLookup`, which is causing the behavior you are currently experiencing.

Also instead of `bind(Class).to(Class)`, you could use `bind(Instance).to(Class)`, which would auto atically make it a singleton, without needing g to specify the scope.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Her is what I did: `public MyConfig () {
 register(new AbstractBinder {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(new ModelDao()).to(IModelDao.class);
            }
        }());
 packages("com.mypackage");
}` and it works.

Answer (score -1):

After you set your class as Singleton do you register it in your application?

Something like this:

```
public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    public App () {
        register(ModelDao.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I register the binder `register(DaoBinder.class);`  then I add the packages containing my dao class and service class `package("com.mypackage");` I read using `package` avoid to `register` all annotated class.

Comment: You can see Jersey documentation https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html. If your problem does not solve i recommend you to implement a simple example from the start with just a singleton class. Also you may want to check Jersey BookStore example https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/bookstore-webapp.